# Ajax redirection with message

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm trying to implement Ajax call in Laravel project. Currently I'm looking for a way to display success/error messages after Ajax successfully execute something & redirect the page.
In Laravel controller, usually I can do it like this:

```php
if($patient->wasRecentlyCreated){
    return redirect('/patients')->with('success','New patient data saved');
} else {
    return redirect('/patients')->with('error','Patient already exist');
}
```

As in the blade view, I have added the message section in the layout page (so that the message will appear on the top of redirected page) :

```html
@if(count($errors)>0)
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{$error}}
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif

@if(session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{session('success')}}
    </div>
@endif
@if(session('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{session('error')}}
    </div>
@endif
```

The case with Ajax call, I'm able to pass the redirect target URL from Laravel controller but I don't know how to pass the success/error message to Ajax.
Below is the sample of Laravel controller I have made to handle the Ajax:

```php
if($settlement->wasRecentlyCreated){
    return url('/patients');
}
```

And in Ajax section, I can redirect using window.location :

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "/createsettlement",
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        billing_id      : billing_id,
        prices          : prices,
        _token          : '{{csrf_token()}}'
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        window.location = data;
    },
```

Any idea how to pass the success/error messages while Ajax do page redirection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `redirect('/page')->with('name', $data)` method **flashes** session data to the currently rendered view. To create **persistent** session data, use `session(['name'=>$data])` instead before the redirect.

Implement it in your code like this:

```php
if($patient->wasRecentlyCreated){
    session(['success'=>'New patient data saved']);
    return redirect('/patients');
} else {
    session(['error'=>'Patient already exist']);
    return redirect('/patients');
}
```

Now, you don't have to worry about the session data being available after a JavaScript redirect. Just ensure you retrieve the session data in which ever page the redirect url is pointing to.

Also, if you want to simulate the default flash behavior you can remove the session data after retrieving them in your blade file like this

```html
@if(count($errors)>0)
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{$error}}
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif

@if(session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{session('success')}}
    </div>
@endif
@if(session('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{session('error')}}
    </div>
@endif

@php
    if(session('success'))
        session()->forget('success');
    if(session('error'))
        session()->forget('error');
@endphp
```

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment, flash session data is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

OK. you can do the redirection and show in the same time.

But considering that ajax is JS you can set a timeout for redirection, i.e.

```
    $('#error-alert').text('The text you want to display').show();
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.location =  url;
    }, 3000); //this case waits 3 secs to redirect to the page you want
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for fast response & good suggestion. I didn't think this approach earlier. Usually with Laravel, the error/success message appear on the destination page after page reload. Is it possible to do the same with jQuery (to maintain the same behaviour with the rest of the pages)?

Comment: You can add the same logic to all your views. Note that i am considering that you are using ajax to send the data. If you are using normal requests you can use sections flashes.